# How to create a cookie to store the 5 last visited web pages in my domain?

Tags: javascript, cookies

What I need is to create a javascript cookie to store something like a local database where when somebody visits a web page and then another (allways under the same domain), that person can see the last web pages from the site, like a history from your web browser.

**Example:**

Someone visits **www.domain.com/webpage1.html** then the same person visits **www.domain.com/webpage2.html**. Three days later that person visits **www.domain.com**, but that person want to know which pages he visited the day after that?

Comment: Please remove the Java tag, as Java is completely different to Javascript and not related to what you are asking about.

Comment: Done, thank you for your observation :)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the cookie in Javascript, as explained here:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

You can add your new page to that cookie (by adding `window.location.href` to it) and keeping a space-separated string value in your cookie, something like

`"domain.com/page1.html domain.com/page2.html domain.com/page3.html"`

Then, you could use PHP to get that cookie, and `explode` it at its spaces, to get the latest URLs, and print them in your page.

Of course, you should find a way in Javascript to only keep 5 URLs, so that your cookie doesn't grow extremely large. For example, you can get the cookie value, `split` that into an array, and then only keep the last 5 values in the array. That shouldn't require much code, and you can also use another cookie to select how many pages to keep in history :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using HTML5, the `localStorage` is another choice. The `localStorage` object stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

You can store and read the visited URLs from localStorage and write a piece of javascript to manage the data.

You can find more details of `localStorage` from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).